# Хлебные крошки php (откуда брать данные)?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть функция:

```
function navigation() {
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    $str = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        $str .= ($arg_list[$i][1] ? 
                    ($arg_list[$i][0] ? 
                        '<a href="' . $arg_list[$i][0] . '">' . $arg_list[$i][1] . '</a>' : 
                        $arg_list[$i][1]
                    ) . ($numargs - 1 > $i && $arg_list[$i][0] ? 
                            '<span>›</span>' : 
                            ''
                        ) : ''
                );
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
echo navigation(
    array('/', 'Главная'), 
    array('/old', 'Чуток ниже'), 
    array('/old-s', 'И еще чуток ниже')
);
```

Откуда брать данные и как вставить в функцию navigation() ?

Comment: Я думаю, что имеет смысл разъяснить, что означают "Хлебные крошки".

Comment: @Denis: Объясните, почему именно вам не подходят другие решения, и что нужно для того, чтобы решение подошло. Без этого нам придётся гадать, что же именно вам нужно. А не зная этого в точности,кому захочется тратить время на ответ?

Comment: @VladD Я не могу понять как применить данную функцию (а точнее откуда берутся данные в array(), из базы данных или из адресной сроки).

Comment: @Denis: Возможно, именно об этом имеет смысл задать вопрос?

Comment: @Denis отредактируйте вопрос, добавте в него саму суть - что вы не можете понять, откуда брать данные. тогда его не будут закрывать как дубликат.

Comment: @Denis, если вы хотите передать что-то в функцию то это выглядит так: `function navigation($param1,$param2) { echo $param1; }`. А какие именно данные нужно передать в функцию, зависит от поставленной задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Имеет смысл посмотреть в БД таблицу со страницами сайта. Наверняка там есть поля типа *path*. Тогда ваша задача — разобрать адрес на компоненты и выбрать из базы названия страниц.

Возьмем ваш пример. Есть страница *http://test/old/older*. Разбирая адрес на компоненты, получаете список адресов страниц:

- /
- /old/
- /old/older

Далее — запрос к БД:

```
SELECT path, title
  FROM pages
 WHERE path IN ('/', '/old/', '/old/older')
```

И собираете все воедино, чтобы передать вашей функции.

Такой вариант сработает, если у вас структура сайта отражается в структуре адресов.